# I cannot add more than one object to my $_SESSION['car'] array

Tags: php, session

so I'm trying to do a basic cart for selling wine. But for some reason, each time I'm trying to add a new product to my cart, my $_SESSION['cart'] array resets itself, and my cart displays only the last object I've added to my $_SESSION['cart'] array.

Here is the code where everything happens:

```
try {
    $validator = new GUMP();

    $_GET = $validator->sanitize($_GET);

    $validation_rules = array(
        'id' => 'required|integer|min_numeric,1'
    );
    $filter_rules = array(
        'id' => 'trim|sanitize_numbers'
    );

    $validator->validation_rules($validation_rules);
    $validator->filter_rules($filter_rules);

    $validated_data = $validator->run($_GET);

    if ($validated_data === false) {
        $errors = $validator->get_errors_array();
        throw new Exception("Invalid wine id: " . $errors['id']);
    }

    $id = $validated_data['id'];
    $wine =Wine::find($id);    

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['cart'] = array($wine);

    if(!in_array($wine,  $_SESSION['cart'])){
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $wine);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Product added to cart';
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Product already in cart';
    }

//dd( $_SESSION['cart']);

    header("Location: cart.php");
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Doesn't `$_SESSION['cart'] = array($wine);` reset the array just after `session_start()`

Comment: Does $wine export an object? Only simple datatypes are allowed. You could serialize it and on read deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do :

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $wine;
```